# Prefetch vs Batching in Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

At a low level, what is the difference between pre-fetch count and batch-size (batching) or how are they related?

To frame it in a different way, does one value have an effect on the other?

Also, is there a way to get all the "pre-fetched" messages in the listener other than Batching?

Answer (score 1):

Prefetch is simply the number of unacknowledged messages the broker allows the consumer to have outstanding.

With the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, pre-fetched messages are held in a queue and passed one-at-a-time to the listener (by default).

Since version 2.2, the container can be configured to pass a "batch" of messages to the listener instead, it uses a combination of batchSize and receiveTimeout to assemble the batch.

This is completely unrelated to the pre-fetch.

However, the batch-size should be less than or equal to the prefetch since, otherwise, the batch size will never be reached and the batch will always be short, and triggered by the `receiveTimeout.